# Pandas: Elementwise typecast

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, types, casting

I have a pandas `datafarme`. One column of that dataframe are ip addresses in `string` format.

```
... | '8.8.8.8' | ...
```

I would like to do an explicit typecast from that string ip address to an `ipaddress.ip_address('ip_string')`. As you can see, the `ipaddress.ip_address` constructor requires an argument. This is why the `astype()` function does not work for me here. Furthermore, I need exception handling in case the string cannot be converted.

Comment: IIUC then `df['ip_string'] = df['ip_string'].apply(ipaddress.ip_address)` should work

Comment: what about errors?

Comment: then you should define your own user func `def foo(x): try: return ipaddress.ip_address(x) except some_error: return '' df['ip_string'].apply(foo)`

Comment: That's how it works. Thanky you! I also tried lambda, which is way slower. However, it still takes > 10 seconds for ~1.2 million lines. Any ideas about that?

Comment: Your problem is that the `ip_address` is not vectorised it only operates on a single string so you'll need to write your own function or see if you use the existing [str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) methods